# Website loads zoomed out or not at all on Chrome for Android

Tags: android, css, html, google-chrome, zooming

Everytime I load my site on Chrome for Android it either loads zoomed, or not at all ( ex: it will display half a text object and stop). I have tried every metatag under the sun to fix it including:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" />

<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

and every combination of 1's and 1.0's I could think of. Site loads fine on chrome and safari for iOS, and on my nexus s stock browser. The only other clue I can think of is when the site loads zoomed in I can scale it back (pinch zoom) which I disallow in my metatag. It's like its not reading it or stopping short somewhere. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a demo site that I can test it on.